# Dynamobd error: Scan Results don't filter to HASH even though I put in an Actual entry ID

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, scanning

I have connected to this local I created dynamo with a Lambda with this code

```
console.log('Starting Function Now');
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'})

exports.handler = function(event,ctx,callback){

    let scanParameters = {
        "TableName": "Accommodation_Request",
        "FilterExpression": "SSD_ID = :val",
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":val": {"N": "2"}},
        "ProjectionExpression": 'SSD_ID,AI_Org_ID'
    };

console.log(scanParameters)

    console.log("Your Student information");
    docClient.scan(scanParameters, function(err,data){
        if(err){
            callback(err, null)
        } else{
            callback(null,data)
        }
    });
};
```

After running the Lambda this I get this outcome

```
{
    "Items": [],
    "Count": 0,
    "ScannedCount": 5
}
```

Problem: I am unable to return the correct scan results with SSD_ID = 1

Answer (score 0):

It could be in case you are using String instead of Number in your filter or you have composite partition key

Comment: I found examples on AWS Docs where they wrote these conditions like this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-FilterExpression

Comment: @tuc94 so, then it’s about partition key selection

Comment: Have you got sort key?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that there is more data to look at. Is there a value in 'LastEvaluatedKey'? When you do a scan operation with a filter you may get no results on a particular request. The `LastEvaluatedKey` value should be passed into the next request's `ExclusiveStartKey`. You can potentially have many empty responses before getting any data. Scans should be used with caution, and generally not be part of production workloads (exceptions do exists, of course).